# Bulk write operation error on server IP:27017. Write errors: [com.mongodb.BulkWriteError@24cd7085]

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, java-8

I am trying to do unordered bulk insert but I am getting write error, and on same single insert is working.

```
    final DBCollection col = db.getCollection(STUDENT);
    BulkWriteOperation bulkop = col.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();

    for(){
    //putting values in doc
    DBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
    //
    bulkop.insert(doc);
    }
        bulkop.execute(WriteConcern.FSYNCED);
```

here is log :

```
Bulk write operation error on server IP:27017. Write errors: [com.mongodb.BulkWriteError@24cd7085]. 
com.mongodb.BulkWriteException: Bulk write operation error on server 192.168.50.166:27017. Write errors: [com.mongodb.BulkWriteError@24cd7085]. 
at com.mongodb.BulkWriteHelper.translateBulkWriteException(BulkWriteHelper.java:57)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeBulkWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:2202)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeBulkWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:2188)
at com.mongodb.BulkWriteOperation.execute(BulkWriteOperation.java:121)
```

I am using Mongo 3.0.4 Java Driver.

Answer (score 0):

For Mongodb-Java 3.0.1 and above , you can use this logic,

```
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("testDB");

        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("testColl").withWriteConcern(WriteConcern.FSYNCED);
        BulkWriteOptions options = new BulkWriteOptions();
        options.ordered(false);

        ArrayList<InsertOneModel<Document>> insertList =  new ArrayList<InsertOneModel<Document>>();
        for(int i =0; i<1000;i++){
            Document document= new Document().append("_id",i).append("testdat", "testvalue");;

            insertList.add(new InsertOneModel<Document>(document));
        }

        collection.bulkWrite(insertList, options);
```